# Get lambda function's name as string

Tags: python, function, lambda

How can I get a lambda function's name?

Using the `__name__` property returns `<lambda>`:

```
def myfunc():
    pass
myfunc_l = lambda :None

print myfunc.__name__
print myfunc_l.__name__

>>myfunc
>><lambda>
```

I was expecting `myfunc_l` but I got `<lambda>`

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I tried it, all I get is <lambda>

Comment: What name do you expect?

Comment: I think there is a reason why lambdas are sometimes called anonymuous functions.

Comment: Python exposes all properties as dictionaries, should be held somewhere.

Comment: @OP: so, if you assigned the same lambda to a second variable, what would you expect the name to be?

Comment: What do you expect `print(lambda: None)` to output?

Comment: `myfunc_l` is the name of a variable, not of a function.

Comment: what would you expect to print in this case `a = myfunc; print(a)`?

Comment: @Ηλίας: The lambda is not a property. It's not held *anywhere* (apart from the stack, which is not a dictionary but a C data structure) until you assign it somewhere. Which is not required.

Comment: like `var=myfunc_l` ? I expect it to still give the string `myfunc_l`. `var` would reference to the lambda function

Comment: @Ηλίας so `myfunc_l` references to the lambda function, too, where should it take the name from?

Comment: @OP: because, sometimes when you assign a lambda to a variable, it takes the name of that variable, but sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: @ScottHunter the lambda does not "take the name of that variable", the name becomes a reference to the lambda.

Comment: If you're just going to assign the lambda to a variable, use a regular function definition.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lambdas are anonymous, which *means* they do not **have** a name.

You can always assign a name to `__name__` if you feel they should have one anyway:

```
myfunc_l = lambda: None
myfunc_l.__name__ = 'foo'
```

Note that Python cannot know that you assigned the `lambda` function object to a specific name; the assignment takes place after the `lambda` expression was executed. Remember, you don't even have to assign a `lambda`:

```
result = (lambda x: x ** 2)(4)
```

or you could store the `lambda` in a list:

```
several_lambdas = [lambda y: (y // 2) for y in range(10, 20)]
```

and in neither context is there a name to assign to these objects.

Full-blown function definitions on the other hand are *statements*, not expressions, and the `def` statement requires that you specify a name. You can never use a `def` statement without naming the resulting function, which is why Python can assign the name to the object:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
...
>>> print foo.__name__
'foo'
```

You can still assign `foo` to something else, delete the `foo` global reference, rename the function object by assigning to the `__name__` attribute, but it won't change the nature of the function. `lambda`s are the same, really, apart from the fact that there's no context to set the initial name (and the fact that they can only represent a single expression).

Answer (score 5):

**Work around:**

Using the inspect module you can do this:

```
from inspect import getsource
get_lambda_name = lambda l: getsource(l).split('=')[0].strip()
print(get_lambda_name(get_lambda_name))

# result: get_lambda_name
```

This way you obtain the source code and extract the "anonymous" name.
Note: this doesn't work in Idle command line.

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda function name is always available as in environment variable, so should be accessible as:

```
os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME']
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: came here from google, the answer fits very well to the question title and that was what I was actually looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can get it from the lambda handler `context` argument.

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html

```
print("function_name:", context.function_name)
```